# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#

This is the first time i am working with Lists and I don't seem to be getting it right. I have a Customer class with a list of customers as a property in the Customer class (can it be done like this?)

```
public class Customer
{
    private List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    public List<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return customers; }
        set { customers = value; }
    }
```

In my program I add to this customer list like this:

```
Customer C = new Customer();
Customer.InputCustomer(C);
C.Customers.Add(C);
```

Now I need to show the customers in this list. I have added a AllCustomers function to the Customer Class like this:

```
public static void AllCustomers()
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in Customers) //Fail on "Customers"
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer ID: " + customer.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Name: " + customer.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Address: " + customer.Address);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting this error in the foreach statement:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AddCustomerList.Customer.Customers.get'

Like I said, this is the first time I am using List, maby i don't understand it right? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you attempting to access the non-static property `Customers` from within a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx) method.

I suspect what you want is this:

```
public void AllCustomers()
{
    // ...
```

(i.e. get rid of the static modifier)

Alternatively you can make both `customers` and the `Customers` members static too:

```
private static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

public static List<Customer> Customers
{
    get { return customers; }
    set { customers = value; }
}
```

Comment: As I commented on the other (now deleted) answer, making `Customers` and `customers` static is not a good idea, it means that every instance of `Customer` will share the same list of customers (and each `Customer` inside each list, for ever). Given that your answer is the accepted one, I suggest deleting the 'Alternatively'...

Answer (score 3):

It fails because `AllCustomers()` is an static method. Remove the 'static' from it and it should compile and work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

As [Gonzalo says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775721/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property/3775739#3775739), you need to remove `static` from the `AllCustomers` method.

Alternatively, you *could* pass in the list of customers to the AllCustomers method, which could continue to be static.

```
public static void AllCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
```

However, I'm curious as to why you have the Customers list *inside* the customers class - is this because your customers have their own customers?