# An object reference is required for non-static field, method, or property in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775721/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

I have a non-static field:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> _mappings = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

that I wnat to use inside of a action like this:

```
public static string GetMimeType(string extension)
{
    //...
    return _mappings.TryGetValue(extension, out mime) ? 
        mime : "application/octet-stream";
}
```

The compiler is complaining:

> An object reference is required for non-static field, method, or
>   property in the return statement.

How can I reference this field?

Comment: Without an instance, you can't. `_mappings` is an instance-only member. `GetMimeType` has no access to instance-variables unless you create an instance inside the method, or pass it one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot access instance members from static members so you have 2 choices.

1. Make the method an instance method (remove the `static` keyword)
2. Make the field a static (add the `static` keyword)

The one you choose will depend on whether the field should be shared across all instances or not.

Comment: Warnings about how making data-carrying members static might lead to unforeseen output should probably be added. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is pretty clear here: Your GetMimeType method is a static method, but the _mappings variable is not declared static (an non-static or instance field/variable).

If you want to use the mappings variable as it appears above do this:

```
private static IDictionary<string, string> _mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Edit: As the commenter pointed out below, you must be careful that this is actually the behavior you want. A static member means all instances will share this same mappings variable and can overwrite the data present. If you want one mappings variable per class, then you should change your method to an instance method (by removing the static keyword), as noted in the answer above.

Comment: Warnings about how making data-carrying members static might lead to unforeseen output should probably be added. =)

Comment: Good point. I was being lazy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a dictionary of values that is populated once and never modified after that, a thing you could do would be make the dictionary static and populate it in a static constructor.