# error learning how to use custom events

Tags: c#, events

i'm learning how to use custom events in c#, but i get some errors
i get "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property" in the bold words

so i tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141323/an-object-reference-is-required-for-non-static-field-method-or-property-in-my)

but case 1 couldn't be tried 'cause TypeChanged is already a nonstatic method (i think)
in case 2 i get "impossible to acces BicycleType as an instance reference, qualify it as a type"

```
public class Bicycle
 {
     public event EventHandler TypeChanged; 
     private string type;
     ...
public string BicycleType {
         get { return this.type; }
         set { 
             this.type = value; 
         if (this.TypeChanged != null) 
             this.TypeChanged( this, new EventArgs() ); 
         }
     }
 
 public Bicycle() {}

 class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("heila!");
        Bicycle istanza = new Bicycle();

        istanza.TypeChanged += new EventHandler(**istanza_TypeChanged**);

        istanza.BicycleType = "io";
        Console.WriteLine("io");

    }

    void istanza_TypeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("rofkd");
    }
 }
```

the tutorial i followed told me i can use events "as" methods, maybe i'm wrong here?
the code is completely similar to te tutorial code

sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are registering the event from the main method, which is static, the event handler (istanza_TypeChanged) has to be made static too.

Comment: do you mean public static event EventHandler TypeChanged;
i get "impossible to acces BicycleType as an instance reference, qualify it as a type" in the propiety

Comment: he means `static void istanza_TypeChanged(object ...`

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that `Main` is static and can therefore not access nonstatic members of the class `Program`. However you try to access `istanza_TypeChanged`. That is what is causing your exception.

You have to make `istanza_TypeChanged` static too to solve the issue

```
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("heila!");
        Bicycle istanza = new Bicycle();

        istanza.TypeChanged += new EventHandler(**istanza_TypeChanged**);

        istanza.BicycleType = "io";
        Console.WriteLine("io");

    }

    static void istanza_TypeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("rofkd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `istanza_TypeChanged` to the following:

```
        private static void istanza_TypeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("rofkd");
        }
```

The following fired the event for me:

```
public class Bicycle
{
    public event EventHandler TypeChanged;
    private string type;

    public string BicycleType
    {
        get { return this.type; }
        set
        {
            this.type = value;
            if (this.TypeChanged != null)
                this.TypeChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public Bicycle()
    {
    }

    private class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("heila!");
            Bicycle istanza = new Bicycle();

            istanza.TypeChanged += istanza_TypeChanged;

            istanza.BicycleType = "io";
            Console.WriteLine("io");

        }

        private static void istanza_TypeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("rofkd");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the event from a non-static context or change your event to be static.