# How to set Default Value in an MVC Model Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class Projects that is defined as follows:

```
public enum ContractFreq
{
    [Display(Name="Monthly")]
    M = 1,
    [Display(Name="Quarterly")]
    Q = 2,
    [Display(Name="Anually")]
    A = 3,
    [Display(Name="One-Time")]
    X = 4
}

public partial class Project
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Project")]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Contract Frequency")]
    public ContractFreq ContractFreq { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Project Start Date")]
    public DateTime? DateStarted { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]

    private String _ProjectName = Vendor.VendorName + " - [" + Description + "]";
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public String ProjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProjectName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProjectName = Vendor.VendorName + " - [" + this.Description + "]";
        }
    }
    /*
    public string ProjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return Vendor.VendorName + " - [" + Description + "]";
        }
    }
     */


    /* Navigation */
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchReq> PurchReqs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        DateStarted = System.DateTime.Now;
        PurchReqs = new HashSet<PurchReq>();
    }
```

and I would like the field "ProjectName" to be the concatentation of Vendor.VendorName and the Project.Description. I know that string parameters can not be null. WHat's the simplest and easiest way to implement this? I originally used:

```
        public string ProjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return Vendor.VendorName + " - [" + Description + "]";
        }
    }
```

but am unable to use linq with non static fields and was wondering if there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It can something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Project Name")]
public String ProjectName
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - [{1}]", Vendor.VendorName, Description );
    }
}
```

and for none static member [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14141380/1385614).