# How to debug "an object reference is required for non static field"

Tags: c#

I am trying to use Linq concept using list items in Visual Studio C#. I am getting error:

> an object reference is required for non static field an object, property, method

for booklist.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Linq.List
{
    public class Books
    {
        string Title="title";
        string Author="author";
        string Publisher="publisher";
        int Year=2000;

        public  List <Books> booklist = new List<Books>
        {
            new  Books
            {
                Title="Programming C#",
                Author="Jesse Liberty",
                Publisher="O'reilly",
                Year=2008
            },
            new  Books
            {
                Title="Learning C#",
                Author="Jesse Liberty",
                Publisher="O'reilly",
                Year=2008
            },
            new  Books
            {
                Title="Programming php",
                Author="Kevin Ludorf",
                Publisher="O'reilly",
                Year=2008
            }
        };

        static void Main()
        {
            var ResultAuthor1= from b in booklist where b ResultAuthor1=="JesseLIberty"
            select new { b.Title,b.Author};

             foreach(var r in ResultAuthor1)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(r.Title+" by "+r.Author);
             }
        }
    }
}       // please rectify this code if there is any error
```

Comment: Make this list static.

Comment: It looks like I misread the error, but the related questions section is full of duplicates, OP put research effort into solving your problem(s)

Comment: Do you want to select ALL books or only those written by Jesse? Because within your loop you print the authors name to the output also, which would always be JesseLiberty in the latter case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775721/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 2):

You may either mark the list static as proposed above from Sébastien Sevrin or create an instance of your `books`-class within Main:

```
Books books = new Books();
var ResultAuthor1= from b in books.booklist where b.Author == "JesseLIberty"
```

Comment: may ask I one question,that i want to learn LINQ concept in detail.Can you suggestion or prescribe some books or video tutorials???

Comment: This will help you to learn LINQ https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Sure, why not use the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx  for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your booklist should be static:

```
public static List <Books> booklist = new List<Books>
    {
        new  Books
        {
            Title="Programming C#",
            Author="Jesse Liberty",
            Publisher="O'reilly",
            Year=2008

        },

         new  Books
        {
            Title="Learning C#",
            Author="Jesse Liberty",
            Publisher="O'reilly",
            Year=2008

        },
         new  Books
        {
            Title="Programming php",
            Author="Kevin Ludorf",
            Publisher="O'reilly",
            Year=2008
        }
    };
```

---

**EDIT**
It looks like you are looking for documentation:
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx) is the MSDN page on this error.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) is another MSDN page with more details on static classes.

Comment: this worked but when we are calling " Console.WriteLine(r.Title+" by "+r.Author);" nothing prints on the screen why??

Comment: @user4862049 - Because there aren't any matches for `JesseLIberty`

Comment: @user4862049: I think you should reformat your code, clean it and explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve

Comment: but my question is that why this error occurred without static???  why C# compiler doest   that??

Comment: if you are access a class member in a method you can create the instance of the class and use the property from that. And If you are using a class property in to static method that should be static.

Comment: @user4862049 The compiler is absolutely right here. Hence we are in a static context (the main-method), we can only access static members. booklist however is undoubtedly non-static, thus you either need an instance for accessing this member or mark that member static.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  public  List <Books> booklist = new List<Books>
```

to

```
  public static List <Books> booklist = new List<Books>
```