# "Object Reference is required for non-static field"

Tags: c#, object, random

So I needed to make a random number generator for my minesweeper project, and I decided to put it in a method.

```
public static void GenerateBombs(int gsize, int numbombs, HashSet<int> numbers)
    {
        int num = gsize * gsize;
        while (numbers.Count < numbombs)
        {
            numbers.Add(Random.Next(1, num));
        }
    }
```

However I keep getting the "Object Reference needed for non-static field, property, or method." I don't know why and I can't figure it out from the other questions.

Comment: Can you show where you've declared `Random`?

Comment: I you want to use `random` in a static function, it have to be `static` too.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: [An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3775721/205233)

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

public static void GenerateBombs(int gsize, int numbombs, HashSet<int> numbers)
{
    int num = gsize * gsize;
    while (numbers.Count < numbombs)
    {
        numbers.Add(rand.Next(1, num));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Next()` of the class `Random` is not a static method. You have to declare an instance of the class `Random` first:

```
static Random random = new Random();
```

then you can use it as `numbers.Add(random.Next(1, num))`, now using the static instance of the class instead of the class itself.